# Finding Difference Between Three Values Using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using a variety of `moment.js` methods to find the difference in milliseconds between values originally represented as dates. This is what I'm doing:

```
const stopTimeLong = '2021-05-19 09:54:08';
const startTimeLong = '2021-05-19 09:54:04';
const currentTimeLong = '2021-05-19 09:54:10'; 

// Get values in milliseconds
const stopTime = moment(stopTimeLong).valueOf();
const startTime = moment(startTimeLong).valueOf();
const currentTime = moment(currentTimeLong).valueOf();

const duration = moment.duration(stopTime - startTime).asSeconds(); // is 4
const final = moment.duration(currentTime - (stopTime - startTime)).asSeconds();
```

Now, the value for `duration` here gives me what I expect based on the initial times: `4`

However the value for `final` is `1621432450` where I would expect `6`.

What is the issue here? What do I need to change in order to get `6` as the final result based on the initial dates?

Comment: the last line should be `const final = moment.duration(currentTime - startTime).asSeconds();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line should be:

```
const final = moment.duration(currentTime - startTime).asSeconds();
```

The stop time is irrelevant, based on the data you gave and the result you asked for.

Comment: Also, you don't need Moment for this, and you should avoid it unless you are already committed to using it in your project.  See [Moment's project status page](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) for further details.  Thanks.